# Creating custom map in android

Tags: android, gps

I need to create a GPS for inside of a store, The idea is to have a picture of the store and as the customer walks in the store the gps show him where he is located and where the things he wants to buy are located (milk on the left, drinks on the right etc.).

The thing is, all the samples i found are based on the google map of the earth. and I need not to be based on them - because I am inside a store and the map is all inside.

Is there API to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are actually people who thought about indoor navigation using GPS. However, even if you are outside and the sky is clean, you will barely get more precision than a few meters (95% between 3 and 15 meters). Inside buildings the accuracy is worse, possibly much worse. I don't want to dissuade you from trying it, but don't be surprised if the results are more or less random. I guess a simple interactive map might be much more helpful than a pseudo-working GPS-based app.

Comment: What do you mean simple interactive? just to show the store on the map witout moving it as he walks? and how do I do that - is there some API for createing this type of map (with zoom in, zoom out method and scrolling the map?).